# Check is key is present and true on key within an optional object?

Tags: typescript

I have an object in this interface:

```
export interface CoolThing {
    thisOptionalField?: {}
}
```

I want to check if `thisOptionalField` has a key on it `myCoolKey` set to `true`.

### Attempt

```
  if (!!ctx.CoolThing?.thisOptionalField && !!ctx.CoolThing?.CoolThing["thisOptionalField"] == true) {
    ....
  }
```

How can I achieve this?

I'm also looking at `[key: string]: unknown`

Answer (score 1):

To check if an object contains a field in JS or TS can be done in a few ways. The easiest way is to do:

```
if (ctx.CoolThing) {
   // has the 'thisOptionalField' field
   if ('thisOptionalField' in ctx.Coolthing) {
      // it is set to true
      if (ctx.Coolthing['thisOptionalField'] === true) {
          // do something
      }
   }
}
```

In TS, I'd recommend you either have `[key: string]: unknown`, or better yet `Record<string, unknown>` instead of an anonymous object like that.

Comment: Ok, cool thanks for the snippet and explanation. I'm using [key: string]: unknown now.